# Approximating a distribution with normal

Tags: normal-approximation

Let's say I generated samples from a distribution $f$ whose functional form I do not know. I want to approximate this distirbution with a multi-variate normal.

We know that if samples are generated using a MVN, then the MLE for mean snd varaince are simply the sample mean and sample co-variance.

My question is that, in my case where I want to approximate with a MVN, would I just use the sample mean and sample co-variance as paramters for the MVN ?

Comment: How did you generate samples without knowing the distribution?

Comment: Its the posterior distribution generated using MCMC for a Bayesian analysis. So I should say that it doesn't have a standard form.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suppose that the posterior is at all close to MVN? If not it might be harder to do better than Laplace approximation to local modes.

Comment: sorry, i don't know about the Laplace approxiamation to local models. We need a standard form for the distribution so that we can use these posterior estimates as priors in another Bayesian analysis. We thought that MVN would be a good approximation. The posterior distirbution, in our case, is a constrained multivaraite distribution, in the semse that all elements should lie on a simplex.

Comment: means and variances alone don't determine a multivariate normal; you need the full covariance matrix.

Comment: yes, sorry, I mean the sample covariance matrix. edited!